# Highcharts Pie chart - 2d array as series

Tags: charts, highcharts, pie-chart

I am using Highcharts to draw some charts, including a pie one. The data needed to draw it are passed as an array, like this

```
data: [pieSeries]
```

The pieSieries array is a 2d array, and when I console.debug it this is the result:
[image]

Now the problem is that the data are not for some reason the chart is not drawn, there is just one line as in the following picture:

[image: pie chart]

Any idea of why this is happening?
Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but negative numbers in a pie chart are not supported..

Comment: Oh, I wasn't thinking about that, but it makes damn perfect sense...thank you for pointing that out Pawel.